# Passing variables to XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am new to XML/XSL. I want to be able to pass a var in a rule string and have that return the correct data.

Right now I have have this PHP:

```
<?php
$params = array('id' => $_GET['id']);

$xslDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xslDoc->load("test.xsl"); 

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load("test.xml");

$xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor(); 
$xsltProcessor->registerPHPFunctions(); 
$xsltProcessor->importStyleSheet($xslDoc); 

foreach ($params as $key => $val)
    $xsltProcessor->setParameter('', $key, $val);

echo $xsltProcessor->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
?>
```

My xml file looks like this:

```
<Profiles> 
  <Profile> 
    <id>1</id> 
    <name>john doe</name> 
    <dob>188677800</dob> 
  </Profile> 
  <Profile> 
    <id>2</id> 
    <name>mark antony</name> 
    <dob>79900200</dob> 
  </Profile> 
  <Profile> 
    <id>3</id> 
    <name>neo anderson</name> 
    <dob>240431400</dob> 
  </Profile> 
  <Profile> 
    <id>4</id> 
    <name>mark twain</name> 
    <dob>340431400</dob> 
  </Profile> 
  <Profile> 
    <id>5</id> 
    <name>frank hardy</name> 
    <dob>390431400</dob> 
  </Profile> 
</Profiles>
```

And my xsl looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="id" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <html><body>
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" border="1"> 
      <caption>User Profiles</caption> 
      <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th></tr> 

      <xsl:for-each select="/Profiles/Profile[id='$id']">
        <tr> 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td> 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="php:function('ucwords', string(name))"/></td> 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="php:function('date', 'jS M, Y', number(dob))"/></td> 
        </tr> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </table> 
    </body></html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I test the url like this:

```
http://foo.com/sanbox/index.php?id=2
```

I only get:

```
Profile
User Profiles ID    Name    Date of Birth.
```

Comment: The  `XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions()` is poorly documented ... See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions

Answer (score 7):

The error is because you havent included the correct namespace.

In your xsl:stylesheet declaration include xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
>
```

Comment: The  `XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions()` is poorly documented ... See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions for more information.

Answer (score 3):

In the XPATH expression there should not be any qoutes around the variable name $id so it should read:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Profiles/Profile[id=$id]">
```

Also, you could put a `<xsl:value-of select="$id"/>` in the document to make sure the value gets passed along.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I'm also new to implementing xsl/xml but i played around with your code for a bit, I couldn't get it working but even if you change

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Profiles/Profile[id='$id']">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Profiles/Profile[id='2']">
```

You still get a nasty error although it does fetch the right information. If you remove any "" or even the '' with anything but numeric it give more errors. I have found another way to do this although i haven't had time to test it. [Client Side XSLT](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/client-side-xslt.html)

I have the same problem as you and would really like to see this problem solved.

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function function bound to undefined prefix php in E:\xampplite\htdocs\XSL\index.php on line 17

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack. in E:\xampplite\htdocs\XSL\index.php on line 17

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function function bound to undefined prefix php in E:\xampplite\htdocs\XSL\index.php on line 17

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: xmlXPathCompiledEval: 2 objects left on the stack. in E:\xampplite\htdocs\XSL\index.php on line 17

Profile

User Profiles
ID  Name    Date of Birth
2   mark antony 79900200

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here stopping it from working, some mentioned already..

The namespace as stated above:

```
<stylesheet xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
```

The for-each...I tend to use:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

then

```
<xsl:for-each select="Profiles/Profile[id=$id]">
```

Also, the quotes wasn't correct, as above, the id doesn't need the ''

With those three changes it works....